# MVC DateFormat show days - hours - minutes until now

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have one app in MVC for editing Users in Database. I also have CreatedDate(when the user was created) but ofcourse it shows me Date and Time when it was Created, but I need it to show me how many days, hours, minutes it was ago.

So when I created user 2 hours ago, it will show me like 0 days 2 hours 0 minutes instead of 8.9.2015 13:48. I know I have to customize this in Model, but I dont really know how. Thanks for help, there is the model.

```
public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```